# how to make entire view in dialog clickable?

Tags: java, android, view, dialog, onclicklistener

i have dialog and text inside eache view that i can click on .
i want all the view to be clickable insted only the text .

the code :

```
        final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(List_Lists.this);
        dialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialog_edit_tables);
        dialog.setTitle("Action for " + table);


        TextView delete = (TextView) dialog
                .findViewById(R.id.tvDeleteTable);
        TextView cancel = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.tvCancel);

        OnClickListener l = new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                dbAdapter = new DBmethods(getApplicationContext());
                switch (v.getId()) {


                case R.id.tvDeleteTable:
                    viewListsAdapter.listsV.remove(pos);
                    dbAdapter.deleteTable(table);
                    break;
                case R.id.tvCancel:
                    dialog.dismiss();
                    break;
                case R.id.bTableRenameName:

                    if(dbAdapter.checkTableNameOK(List_Lists.this  ,newName.getText().toString())){

                        viewListsAdapter.listsV.remove(pos);
                        viewListsAdapter.listsV.add(pos, newName.getText().toString().trim());
                        dbAdapter.renameTable(table , newName.getText().toString().trim());
                        renamedialog.dismiss();
                    };

                    break;

                default:
                    break;
                }
                // if button is clicked, close the custom dialog
                dialog.dismiss();
                lv.invalidateViews();
            }
        };

        delete.setOnClickListener(l);
        cancel.setOnClickListener(l);

        dialog.show();
    }
});
```

}

as i said this code work fine if user press on text inside the view , but the empty view obviously wont respond .  thanks !

[image: if user press on red spot it activate the enter , if green than duplicate and so on]

if user press on red spot it activate the enter , if green than duplicate and so on...the current status is u have to press on the word , if u press on the colored spots it will do nothing

Comment: Sorry but I didn't get you

Comment: make layout clickable @Jesus Dimrix

Comment: i have dialog with view and text inside each view . i want to perform action when spcific view is pressed . in this dialog i have to press the text inside the view . hope i"m explaining right

Answer (score 1):

If im not wrong you need this to make layout clickable

try something like this
You can add a OnClickListener on it :

```
//onCreate
LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.LinearLayout01);
layout.setOnClickListener(yourOnClickListener);
```

Should be working ;)

Answer (score 0):

create an id of your `dialog_edit_tables`

let say `android:id=@+id\testing` in your xml.

now write this

```
LinearLayout yourlayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.testing);
yourlayout.setOnClickListener(l);
```

hope this will help.

Comment: your answer is great but i missexplained what i want . i added picture to the question .

thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

You haven't shown the XML layout but setting the width of the clickable text view to fill_parent should work, also make sure your parent layout also has the width set to fill_parent.

The onClickListener is not based on the text it is based on the actual component, therefore it looks as if the layout_width attribute is set to wrap_content, so the component is only then length of the text, therefore only where the text is, is clickable. Hope this makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

If I am not wrong than you are using `listview` or `tableview` to display the text. 
You can do one thing.
 Make the textview `layout_width` as `fill_parent`
 That way you will able to get the touch on the place that you marked.
Hope this will help.